# Access denied errors by server itself on uploaded files?

Tags: drupal, logs, lts

I'm noticing a lot in the logs whereby the server itself is trying to request a resource that CiviCRM denies access to by `.htaccess`.

Specifically it seems the CiviCRM server is trying to fetch files of this pattern:

```
/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/delete-this-d3542fs2sP
/sites/default/files/civicrm/custom/delete-this-D44i89qZNP
```

Yet both of those directories contain `.htaccess` files with `Deny all` statements.

Anyone shed any light on this? [4.4.20 LTS, Drupal 7]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have discovered that the `delete-this` files are temporary files created by CiviCRM for the sole purpose of generating this error! This error is **good**, it means that these directories are not browseable, and they shouldn't be browseable.

CiviCRM's `CRM_Utils_Check_Security` class does these checks in order to report what would-be security errors.

It creates a file, then tries to access that file via http. This should fail.

Comment: Civi's security-checking functions also make sure that the debug log (`ConfigAndLog.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.log`) is not web-accessible. See this related question: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11918/howto-fix-client-denied-by-server-configuration?noredirect=1&lq=1