# 4 minutes to access admin page

Tags: wordpress, performance

I have a similar issue of the 2017 post
[first CiviCRM request of each session takes 4 minutes, afterwards works fine](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22068/first-civicrm-request-of-each-session-takes-4-minutes-afterwards-works-fine)

I have a fresh virtual server in a university saas, with wordpress 5.9.2, php 7.4, no extension, civicrm. The first time after logging, if i click on civcrm, i have to wait 4 minutes before i can acces the menus. I tried everything (anothers virtual machines, with or without databases, change php version, etc..). I just found the other post today. No luck,
i changed in civicrm.settings.php the CICICRM_CMSDIR
CIVICRM_CMSDIR', '/home/entetu/htdocs/wp-content/') and no change
on my local server, netcat on ports 80 and 443 are open
So i need to disable checks but i don't know how to do it.
Can somone give me a hand on this, please ?

Comment: This does seem like it's the same cause as the other post. Turn off version checks under Administer - System Settings - Scheduled Jobs. And then also the other setting it mentions in civicrm.settings.php - https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/24453/181

Answer (score 0):

I turned off Scheduled jobs, but no effect.
now, i've got a message :
The CiviCRM public extensions directory at [https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver=5.47.2|cms=WordPress](https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver=5.47.2%7Ccms=WordPress) could not be contacted - please check your webserver can make external HTTP requests. Contact your site administrator for assistance.

In civicrm.settings.php i uncommented // $civicrm_setting['domain']['ext_repo_url'] = false;
and the access is immediate. So the problem is the extensions.

I work behind a proxy server, so there must be a connection problem to reach the external extensions.
I found in
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-cxn-rpc/blob/master/doc/proxy.md
define('CIVICRM_CXN_VIA', 'proxy_address:PORT');

a way to indicate a proxy to civicrm but it didn't work.
Any clue for another way to fix proxy with Civicrm ?

Comment: Can you access other external sites from within your network without a proxy?  On one site it was finding an IPv6 address and attempting to use that but blocked by the internal network.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  To preserve the usefulness of this site to folks with the same question as you, you shouldn't put non-answers in the "Answers" section.  Please edit the original question to include this information and delete this answer?