# HowTo fix: client denied by server configuration?

Tags: drupal, permissions, logs

looking in my Apache error logs I get a lot of these errors:

```
17:52:59    client denied by server configuration: /path/to/drupal/sites/default/files/civicrm/custom/delete-this-hLW0uQKV0o    error   
17:52:59    client denied by server configuration: /path/to/drupal/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/delete-this-2oysK1uZ8L    error   
17:52:58    client denied by server configuration: /path/to/drupal/sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.3de7c305138430bacabc11877313657f.log    error
```

The directory permissions for sites/default/files/civicrm and all its subdirectories are 775

```
drwxrwxr-x  45 web  www   140B 19 Mai 10:45 ..
drwxrwxr-x   2 web  www   369B 19 Mai 09:29 custom
drwxrwxr-x   2 web  www     4B 19 Mai 09:29 upload
drwxrwxr-x   2 web  www    10B  1 Mai 05:15 ConfigAndLog
drwxrwxr-x   3 web  www     4B  3 Dez 23:26 persist
drwxrwxr-x   4 web  www     4B  3 Dez 23:22 templates_c
drwxrwxr-x   7 web  www     7B  3 Dez 23:22 .
```

and are owned by the apache user

```
uid=1001(web) gid=1000(www) groups=1000(www)
```

so in principle even 755 should be enough.

I don't think it is related to any [apache](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration) setting (using 2.4), since my folder with drupal inside is inside a directory which already has a Require all granted directive, and my other web projects (and drupal itself) do not throw such kind of errors.

Understanding [this](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7756/access-denied-errors-by-server-itself-on-uploaded-files) post right it is kind of "normal" that the "delete-this" files through an error?
Even if, why this also happens for the log file? Looking into the folder ConfigAndLog I have observed that each month a new file is created. But each month I have to chmod the newly created file in order that the apache user can write into it.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

See [Access denied errors by server itself on uploaded files](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7756/access-denied-errors-by-server-itself-on-uploaded-files/8292?s=1%7C0.4142#8292), which you refer to in your question. The answer there applies to the ConfigAndLog file too. Civi periodically runs tests to make sure that certain directories and files are **not** accessible via the web. These include:

- the current debug log file (`ConfigAndLog.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.log`)
- the image upload directory (on your Drupal site, this is `sites/default/files/civicrm/upload`)
- the custom php directory (on your Drupal site, this is `sites/default/files/civicrm/custom`)

The "client denied by server configuration" entries in your error.log are an indication that those directories and files are protected as they should be.

As the author of the security-check function writes in a code comment:

> Per CiviCRM default the logfile sits in a folder which is web-accessible, and is protected by a default .htaccess configuration. If server config causes the .htaccess not to function as intended, there may be information disclosure.
>
> The debug log may be jam-packed with sensitive data, we don't want that.

In other words, it's good that the debug log is not accessible via the web.