# AH01797: client denied by server configuration

Tags: error

```
[Tue Jul 12 21:36:24.720900 2016] [access_compat:error] [pid 5387] [client 192.158.31.162:44948] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/XXX/sites/def
ault/files/civicrm/custom/delete-this-yeIAcdkLVh
```

Hi

I'm getting this in my apache logs when trying to delete some custom data fields left over from a bad extension installation. On screen it spins forever when trying to delete.

Anyone know where to start troubleshooting?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The message that you're seeing in your Apache error.log may just be coincidental with your custom field issue. Those error.log messages are created when Civi checks itself to make sure certain directories and files are not accessible via the web. For more information, see [Access denied errors by server itself on uploaded files?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7756/access-denied-errors-by-server-itself-on-uploaded-files/8292?s=1|0.4142#8292).